# Facebook iFrame app not showing up in Mountain Lion OS

Tags: facebook, osx-mountain-lion

This is weird. I created a [Facebook iFrame App](http://www.facebook.com/YellowMountainStoneWorksInc/app_473880402626901) that worked fine in every browser I've tested it on. Then Mountain Lion came out. For some reason macs running the new OS and Safari 6 can't see the app. The Facebook chrome is there, but the website isn't loading. (The app is just a website hosted elsewhere). I have another mac running lion that has Safari 6, but it works fine. So it has to be Mountain Lion that's causing this problem. I don't see how the operation system would affect this, but it seems to be.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No matter what browser I am using, the address `https://www.yellow-mountain.com/latest_picture/` is not reachable (my browsers try to connect to the HTTPS version because I am browsing FB over HTTPS). And even outside any iframes I can not connect to that address. Reaching it just via HTTP works fine though. So talk to your server admin about getting SSL to work for your server/domain.

Comment: Thanks CBroe for the suggestion. I'll look into it more. (if this turns out to be the correct answer how do I give you credit?)

Comment: I talked to our server admin - he added SSL and everything works now. Thanks CBroe! How can I give you credit and close this question?

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what browser I am using, the address https://www.yellow-mountain.com/latest_picture/ is not reachable (my browsers try to connect to the HTTPS version because I am browsing FB over HTTPS). And even outside any iframes I can not connect to that address.

Reaching it just via HTTP works fine though.

So talk to your server admin about getting SSL to work for your server/domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the browser's cache. It works pretty well for me.